# Syntax for projectjobscheduling examples

Tags: optaplanner

I am planning to use Optaplanner as engine for a development and I am playing with the examples just to get the feeling of the product.
THe example "projectjobscheduling" fits quite well my needs and I would like to try and use it as proof of concept to show to my boss (who has to authorize me continuing my developments on this path).

I have some real data from a customer that I would like to model as a projectjobscheduling example. 
I have found the example specifications here

http://allserv.kahosl.be/mista2013challenge/files/problem-description.pdf

According to the pdf the  PSPLIB MRCPSP le format is available here
(
     `http://129.187.106.231/psplib/`

), but the site is unreachable.

Do you know any alternative source for the syntax? 
Also commented example files (I mean more commented than the ones included in the distro) would be helpful.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the java code in [ProjectJobSchedulingImporter](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/optaplanner/blob/master/optaplanner-examples/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/examples/projectjobscheduling/persistence/ProjectJobSchedulingImporter.java#L63).

Or ask on [the MISTA google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mista-2013-challenge).